# Unable to import after declarations

Tags: go, syntax

I'm trying to import some modules after the declarations in Go.

For instance, I've tried importing the time time after declaring a variable but that doesn't work , can someone please tell me why that happens in Go?

This works:

```
package main

import (
       "fmt"
)
import "time";

var test = "testing"

func main() {
    currtime := time.Now()

    fmt.Println(test) 
    fmt.Println(currtime)//Output: 16:44:53
```

}

But thid doesn't:

```
package main

import (
       "fmt"
)

var test = "testing"
import "time"

func main() {
    currtime := time.Now()

    fmt.Println(test) 
    fmt.Println(currtime)//Output: 16:44:53

}
```

The error is "non-declaration statement outside function body". 
Why does that happen in Go?

Comment: I thing this is a choice of the creators so the code is more readable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The error is "non-declaration statement outside function body". Why does that happen in Go?

Because this is how Go is defined to work.  From [the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Source_file_organization):

> Each source file consists of a package clause defining the package to which it belongs, followed by a possibly empty set of import declarations that declare packages whose contents it wishes to use, followed by a possibly empty set of declarations of functions, types, variables, and constants.

This means that the *only* valid place for import statements is between the `package` clause, and declarations of functions, types, variables, and constants.

In your case, you have a variable declaration, so the Go compiler knows there will be no more import statements. Then it sees your erroneous import statement, sees that it is a non-declaration, and correctly generates the error you observe.

Answer (score 2):

> why does that happen in go lang ?

Because it is disallowed by the language spec. Pretty simple, or?

Answer (score 1):

You usually have two ways to import packages in Go:

```
import "fmt"
import "time"
```

Or

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)
```

The trick is that you cannot have a mix of `import` and something else like in your second example.

```
package main

import (
       "fmt"
)

var test = "testing" //<-- This does not comply with the definition of a Go file
import "time"

func main() {
    currtime := time.Now()

    fmt.Println(test) 
    fmt.Println(currtime)//Output: 16:44:53

}
```

> Here you can find a well done documentation of the [Anatomy](https://medium.com/golangspec/import-declarations-in-go-8de0fd3ae8ff) of .go file.
>
> Structure of every .go file is the same.
>
> - First is package clause optionally preceded with comments usually describing the purpose of the package.
> - Then zero or more import declarations.
> - 3rd section contains zero or more top-level declarations

Comment: "You usually have two ways.."  usually?  Except for when?

Comment: Except for the first example given by the OP where he has an ugly mix of both... But even if it's ugly it compiles.